# SAS EG Character Functions

Tags: string, sas, character, enterprise-guide

I have two tables containing characters:

```
      First_Column            Second Column
          aaa                   123aaa123
          bbb                   cdsbbbsxd
          ccc                   098fdsccd
```

I want to label 1 if Second Column string contains the string in the first column otherwise I would like put 0.

I could not find a way to do that in SAS EG? Is there any function to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions like `find`, `index` or `count`.

```
count('Second Column'n, First_Column)

index('Second Column'n, First_Column)

find('Second Column'n, First_Column)
```

In Query Builder you have to add new column with an expression like below:

```
case(count('Second Column'n, First_Column))
  when(0) then 0
  else 1
end
```